# Wordpress How to COPY TEXT to CLIPBOARD

Tags: javascript, wordpress, copy, clipboarddata

I need a copy-to-text button using a font awesome icon in a div in wordpress.

I do not want any alerts. Just a simple click.

```
<div class="btcTXT">text</div>

<div id="cpy" class="cpy"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></div>
```

I am a novice so please tell me the steps I need to do.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `div` an id first, like so:

```html
<div class="btcTXT" id="your-div-id">text</div>
```

Then write this javascript to do the trick for you!

```js
document.getElementById("cpy").addEventListener("click", () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementById("your-div-id").textContent).then(() => {
        console.log('Copied to clipboard!!!');
    });
});
```

Make sure you "enqueue/inject" your javascript to the page you're testing.

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Comment: How do I place javascript inside a wordpress page?  Its doesn't seem to work if I add it to the page.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "enqueue/inject"

Comment: I can't seen to figure out how to place the javascript.

Comment: In wordpress you need to load your javascript onto the page. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I just tested it on my wordpress website and it works seamlessly fine.

Comment: Yes, please. How do you load javascript on the page?

Comment: Don't I need to make reference to <div id="cpy" class="cpy"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></div> ??

Comment: I've already done that in the javascript! In your wordpress root directory, create a javascript file and call it, let's say, "test.js", copy the javascript code that i gave you above and paste it into the "test.js". Then in the root folder of your active theme find a file called "functions.php", open it up and copy the following code into it, save it and load your wordpress. ```add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {wp_enqueue_script('test_js', get_theme_file_uri('test.js'), "", microtime(), false);});```

Comment: Where do I put the test.js?

Comment: In the root directory of your active theme.

Comment: If i were you, i would find a developer and ask him/her to do it for me. The script that I've provided, is tested and works. I'll leave it here for future reference.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a pop up window plugin

Answer (score 0):

What @Ruvee said is correct. You typically need to [enqueue scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) on your site to make sure everything works as expected. If that isn't your cup of tea I would suggest using a plugin like [Simple CSS and JS Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/).

You can add that piece of code as a new JS file using that plugin and should work just fine.